# httpService undefined error when making http request in Nest JS

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

I am trying to make a third-party API call in my Nest JS app. Since Nest JS uses Axios under the hood and has a dedicated page for it in their doc here https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module, I made sure to follow the implementation as provided on the doc but I keep running into **httpService undefined** error when I tried to make the HTTP request through the httpModule from Nestjs. I am not sure what I am missing and I've tried to search for the related issue here but with no luck. Kindly help take a look, below is a sample of my code.

bankVerification.service.ts

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

config();

export class BankVerificationService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

  getBanks(countryCode): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {

    console.log(this.httpService, '===============')
    return this.httpService.get(`https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/${countryCode}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.FLUTTERWAVE_TEST_SECRET}`
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Below is my HTTP module config for Axios

```
import { Module, HttpModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BankVerificationService } from '../payment/utils/bankVerification.service';

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule.register({
    timeout: 3000,
  })],
  providers: [BankVerificationService],
})
export class ExternalHttpRequestModule {}
```

Below is the screenshot of the error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: Seems like a DI issue. Maybe try to add the `@Injectable` decorator to the service?

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe I missed that. It was indeed a Dependency Injection issue due to the lack of the **@Injectable** decorator just like you pointed out.

Thank you so much [@MorKadosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625444/morkadosh) for the answer. It worked. Make it an answer let me accept it please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You decorate all classes with @Injectable decorator that are using Dependency Injection feature of Nest.js

here you can read more about how Dependency Injection works in Nest.js https://docs.nestjs.com/providers